# xgettext does not extract string in HTML attribute

Tags: wordpress, twig, poedit, xgettext, timber

I'm working on a Wordpress site using Timber as templating engine (twig for Wordpress). I want to translate the interface using the Wordpress gettext mechanism via PoEdit (uses xgettext).

Template snippet:

```
<form action="/{{ current_language }}/api/search/{{ viewModel.currentSuperCategory.key }}"
  method="post"
  class="search-results__search"
  id="search-form">
<input placeholder="{{ __('City, region, ZIP', text_domain) }}&hellip;"
       class="input search-results__search__input"
       name="search-query"
       type="text"
       data-search-autocomplete />
```

I'm using PoEdit to extract the strings from the *.twig file.

It **is** working if I place *{{ __('City, region, ZIP', text_domain) }}* on a separate line in the template, but it **is not** working when placed in the input placeholder as shown in the snippet above.

I configured PoEdit as explained here: https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/Text-Cookbook#generating-po-files-using-poedit

Does anybody have an idea why that is the case? Is xgettext ignoring strings inside of HTML attributes?

Another example:

In the following case the strings get extracted for translation:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
{{ __('Search subscription', text_domain) }}
{{ __('Save free search subscription', text_domain) }}
```

But not in the following case:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
<span data-rt-xs="{{ __('Search subscription', text_domain) }}" data-rt-lg="{{ __('Save free search subscription', text_domain) }}"></span>
```

Comment: The two best solutions are: (1) Make Twig create cache versions of all template files. These are actual PHP files. Then let `xgettext` or Poedit operate on these cache files instead. (2) Poedit 2 Pro seems to have built-in Twig support.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665666/how-to-parse-timber-twig-templates-with-poedit-and-detect-quoted-strings-to-tr and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243278/poedit-doesnt-extract-string-in-html-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because you are not actually extracting from “HTML atttributes”, but from a template language that `xgettext` has no support for. To work around that you are, I’m guessing, using the gross Python hack from that page. In effect, *you are lying to xgettext/Poedit about what the file contains*, with results that are, frankly, to be expected. Is the file a valid *Python* file? No, it isn’t, it’s *Twig*. You can’t really expect it to be parsed correctly when you mislead the tool about the language.

Instead, I recommend doing what that page also recommends, and as a better way:

> A nicer solution is to use [Twig-Gettext-Extractor](https://github.com/umpirsky/Twig-Gettext-Extractor), a special Twig parser to Poedit. The linked page contains instructions on how to set it up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are of course right about the Python workaround being a hack. I had also tried to use the Twig-Gettext-Extractor. But the command itself is not working: 
RuntimeException: Gettext command `"xgettext --sort-output [...]  failed with error code 1 and output: `. I can't debug it, since it's a system command, and the error is not really helping. I will try to get it to work though.