# How to parse Timber (twig) templates with poedit and detect quoted strings to translate

Tags: html, internationalization, poedit, timber

I want to parse twig templates for Timber with poedit and I need to translate quoted contents. The problem is that I can't find a parser that does not skip quoted content.

Example:

```
<htmltag attribute="{{ __('value','textdomain') }}" />
```

Does someone know of a parser for poedit that detects quoted content, like html attribute content?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243278/poedit-doesnt-extract-string-in-html-tags and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33910482/xgettext-does-not-extract-string-in-html-attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround I found is to set a variable and use it as my attribute value.

```
{% set attr_value = __('value', 'textdomain') %}
<a href='{{ attr_value }}'>link</a>
```

This way, the PHP and Python parsers work, as suggested in the [Timber documentation](https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/Text-Cookbook#generating-po-files-using-poedit).

Using [Twig-Gettext-Extractor](https://github.com/umpirsky/Twig-Gettext-Extractor), I get a Twig-Error-Syntax because of unrecognized __() function.

Comment: Good news, [Poedit 2 is here](https://poedit.net/news/introducing-poedit2). With the paid PRO version, you get full support for Twig and translations inside HTML attributes also work.

Answer (score 1):

Twig files are not automatically recognized when you use Poedit. To work around this, [Timber’s documentation offers three options](http://timber.github.io/timber/#generating-po-files-using-poedit):

- Either start each `.twig` file with `{#<?php#}`
- Or use [The Twig Gettext Extractor](https://github.com/umpirsky/Twig-Gettext-Extractor), a «poedit-friendly tool which extracts translations from twig templates».
- Or use a Python parser. Refer to the [documentation](http://timber.github.io/timber/#generating-po-files-using-poedit) on how to set this up in Poedit.

I went with option 3 and it worked nicely.

Comment: Did you try with the example provided in the question? For me, it does not work.

Comment: Just tried. You’re right, your use case doesn’t work with the Python parser. Here’s why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34249157/1059980. I guess we have to wait for Poedit 2, where template languages seem to be supported better and until then, work with the solution you came up with.

Comment: Thanks @Gchtr for the try and for the hint about poedit 2!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with OSX Sierra, and none of the three solutions worked for me:

- Using `{#<?php#}` on top of my .twig files caused poedit not to tecognize my strings
- Using  Twig-Gettext-Extractor throw many errors
- Using python compile throw many errors too

I solved using the first option ( `{#<?php#}` on top of my .twig files ) but I also edited PoEdit PHP extractor in order it can search also in .twig files.
I hope this can help,

cheers!

Comment: Was it really a problem of attribute translation?